# ADF Table - How to have two of the same tables on a page without replication

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have two tables that are identical, but need to show different data on the same page.  How can I do this without having to maintain an exact copy of the af:table ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Taskflow should contain your table , pass params to Taskflow and use them in View criteria or bind variable . Beans should be defined in Backing Scope.So your page will have two regions showing the same table with different data.

Hope it helps.

-Siddharth